# The Command enables the Button in Xamarin Prism

Tags: xamarin, command, prism

I am working with Xamarin Prism, I'm trying to disable the button, but whenever I add the command it enables. What can this be ?

**Code:**

```
<Button       
  Command="{Binding save}"
  IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [document of Button.Command Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.command?view=xamarin-forms) we can see:

> This property is used to associate a command with an instance of a
>   button. This property is most often set in the MVVM pattern to bind
>   callbacks back into the ViewModel. **IsEnabled** is controlled by the
>   Command if set.

So, if you don't set the command property, it will work correctly.

If you set the command property, the `isEnable` is controlled by the Command itself.

Here I wrote an example to show you how to control the button's enable property in the command:

In the xaml:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:CommandDemoViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Divide by 2"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Command="{Binding DivideBy2Command}"  
            />
</StackLayout>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
class CommandDemoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Command DivideBy2Command { private set; get; }

    public CommandDemoViewModel()
    {
        DivideBy2Command = new Command(()=> performCommandAction(), ()=>isButtonEnable());
    }

    private bool isButtonEnable()
    {

        //Handle the if the button isEnable here
        //Reture ture or false with your own logic here to control the button's isEnabled

        return false;
    }


    private void performCommandAction()
    {
        //Handle the button click logic here 
    }

}
```

Use the constructor `public Command(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute);`.

You can control the isEnable by the  command's `CanExecute`. Reture ture or false with your own logic in the method `isButtonEnable` to control the button's `isEnabled`.